# Detecting circle pattern in image using Python & OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, object-detection, canny-operator

I've got images like this one:

[image: Start image]

I need to detect the center of this circular element:

[image: Detected graft image]

(More precisely - I'm looking for the midpoint of the circular element)

Currently my code detect the mold (the plastic circle that holds the circular element) and select the rectangle ROI to focus the image into the relevant area:

```
import cv2
import imutils
import numpy as np

if __name__ == "__main__":
    image = cv2.imread('Dart - Overview Image - with Film.bmp')
    img = imutils.resize(image, width=700)
    image = img

    output = image.copy()
    roi = image.copy()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # cv2.imshow("Gray", gray)
    # cv2.waitKey(0)

    # detect circles in the image
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.2, 100)

    # ensure at least some circles were found
    if circles is not None:
        # convert the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles to integers
        circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")
        # loop over the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles
        for (x, y, r) in circles:
            # draw the circle in the output image, then draw a rectangle
            # corresponding to the center of the circle
            cv2.circle(output, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.rectangle(output, (x - 2, y - 2), (x + 2, y + 2), (0, 128, 255), -1)
            roi = roi[y - r: y + r, x - r: x + r]
        cv2.imshow("img", roi)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This will show this image:

[image: ROI image]

Now, I'm trying to find the midpoint of the circular element inside this ROI image by detecting the circular element but It's challenged for me, I've try this methods:

```
    gray_roi = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray_roi, (3, 3), 0)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
    cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
    cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)

    for c in cnts:
        (x, y), radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
        cv2.circle(roi, (int(x), int(y)), int(radius), (35, 255, 12), 3)
        cv2.circle(roi, (int(x), int(y)), 1, (35, 255, 12), 2)
        print(x, y)
        break

    # Find Canny edges
    edged = cv2.Canny(roi, 30, 121, apertureSize=3, L2gradient=True)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    # Finding Contours
    # Use a copy of the image e.g. edged.copy()
    # since findContours alters the image
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edged,
                                           cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

    cv2.imshow('Canny Edges After Contouring', edged)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

And got this output:

[image: Threshold image]

I've also tried to change the threshold parameters in the `cv2.Canny` function but it's didn't give me better results.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried any masking ?

Comment: I'm still not that well versed in the field, could you please give me examples of masks that you think could help me and I'll try to check with them?

Comment: Are you trying to detect the graft for this particular image? if no, will the graft be in the same area of the frame?

Comment: I'm trying to detect graft in general images while always there is an mold (plastic circle) that I'm detecting simply with the opencv algorithm, but the graft can be in any area inside the mold (the mold is the ROI that I currently detect successfully)

Comment: The final result you are looking for is the center of the image?

Comment: I'm looking for the center point of the graft